# Boost Shared Container Iterator equivalent in standard C++

Tags: c++, boost

I have a piece of code containing boost::shared_container_iterator which needs a boost::shared_ptr which in turn uses deprecated std::auto_ptr.

I would like to get rid of every auto_ptr dependency but I am not sure how to do it in this case.

Is there any equivalent to boost::shared_container_iterator in standard library? As far as I understand it is used as a generator, so maybe std::input_iterator is a good alternative?

Comment: are you writing C++03 ?

Comment: I'm trying to port code to c++17

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't, but `boost::shared_container_iterator` is so simple (almost all the work is done by `boost::iterator_adaptor`) that you should be OK to copy it into your own utility library, changing `boost::shared_ptr` to `std::shared_ptr` (and updating the coding style):

```
template<class Container>
class shared_container_iterator :
    public boost::iterator_adaptor<shared_container_iterator<Container>, typename Container::iterator>
{
    std::shared_ptr<Container> ref;
public:
    shared_container_iterator() = default;
    shared_container_iterator(typename Container::iterator x, std::shared_ptr<Container> c) :
        shared_container_iterator::iterator_adaptor(x), ref(std::move(c)) {}
};

template<class Container>
auto make_shared_container_range(std::shared_ptr<Container> const& container) {
    return boost::make_iterator_range(
        shared_container_iterator{container->begin(), container},
        shared_container_iterator{container->end(), container});
}
```

Note that this still uses [Boost.IteratorAdaptor](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/libs/iterator/doc/html/iterator/generic/adaptor.html), but that should be fine to use in modern C++.

[Example](https://godbolt.org/z/GDrHTb).